# Criar parâmetros em div para usar no Javascript

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se eu posso criar parâmetros personalizados dentro de uma `div` e se é recomendado pelo W3C, pois gostaria de criar alguns parâmetros para uma tag, mas não achei nenhuma referência na internet, um exemplo abaixo com o parâmetro **abacaxi**

```
<div class="teste" abacaxi="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso a prática são campos `data-`. Muito à semelhança do que fizeste, mas seria

```
<div class="teste" data-abacaxi="false"></div>
```

Em HTML isso [chama-se atributos `data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) e [há uma API para usar isso em JavaScript que é `.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), e que retorna um *"map of DOMString"*, semelhante a um objeto.

Um exemplo seria:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var valor = div.dataset.abacaxi;
console.log(valor);
```

```html
<div class="teste" data-abacaxi="false"></div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, acho que eu não estava procurando direito, mas vlw mesmo assim!